How to implement a wide multi-level self-join PostgreSQL query?
I have several rows that represent a person. Each person has a column for bio_mother _uuid and a bio_father_uuid. I used this page (I mention that because it's referenced in this similar question) to implement this join.
SELECT 
base.uuid base_uuid, base.created_at base_created_at, base.givenname base_givenname, base.bio_mother_uuid base_bio_mother_uuid, base.bio_father_uuid base_bio_father_uuid,
mother.uuid mother_uuid, mother.created_at mother_created_at, mother.givenname mother_givenname, mother.bio_mother_uuid mother_bio_mother_uuid, mother.bio_father_uuid mother_bio_father_uuid,
father.uuid father_uuid, father.created_at father_created_at, father.givenname father_givenname, father.bio_mother_uuid father_bio_mother_uuid, father.bio_father_uuid father_bio_father_uuid
FROM person AS base
LEFT JOIN person AS mother ON base.bio_mother_uuid = mother.uuid
LEFT JOIN person as father ON base.bio_father_uuid = father.uuid;

I am hoping to unmarshal rows into this Go struct
type Person struct{
  UUID string
  Givenname string
  Bio_mother *Person
}

If I query using the query above, I get NULLs for every person who doesn't have mother or father data (this is good), but then when building the mother/father data, I end up building incomplete instances of Person since I don't have the "grandparent" data in the query. I could solve this by implementing logic in the code to query again if there exists a UUID but that slows down the program significantly than somehow doing this in the query.
This is a learning project for me but I'm not entirely sure what to google to come to a good answer.
How can I adapt my query to handle my use case AND return in only a single row? It'll have to do with a recursive CTE but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it after reviewing some PostgreSQL Tutorial pages
Edit:
I realized that missing data means having to name these columns dynamically, or maybe some code? Maybe additive prefixes? In this example output I just use "alias". Notice how Gertrude is missing mother data there's a gap on the rows. That is because the pattern has always been mothers first, not sure if I even agree that that modelling of the pattern makes sense, but this is the model I can come up with right now for this data. Please let me know if I'm shooting off in a wrong direction
(I've also shortened the columns down to "other stuff" after the first couple iterations for readability and I'm getting on a train without wifi so want to get this question prepped and off)
Example Input and Output
Example Data



uuid
givenname
surname
bio_mother_uuid
bio_father_uuid




aa
david
smith
ab
ac


ab
mary
smith
ad
ae


ac
john
smith
af
ag


ad
gertude
snow

ah


ae
Richard
snow




af
Katie
smith




ag
Mathew
smith




ah
Winston
Snow





Desired Output



base_uuid
base_givenname
base_surname
base_bio_mother_uuid
base_bio_father_uuid
mother_uuid
mother_givenname
mother_surname
mother_bio_mother_uuid
mother_bio_father_uuid
father_uuid
father_otherstuff
alias_uuid
alias_otherstuff
alias_uuid
alias_otherstuff
alias_uuid
alias_otherstuff
alias_uuid
alias_otherstuff
alias_uuid
alias_otherstuff




aa
david
smith
ab
ac
ab
mary
smith
ad
ae
ac
john smith..
ad
gertrude snow
ae
richard snow
af
katie smith
ag
mathew smith


winston snow


ab
mary
smith
ad
ae
ad
gertrude
snow

ah
ae
richard snow


ah
winston snow









GITHUB REPO FOR THIS WORK

Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question. Also, please don’t link to external sites, questions on this forum need to be self-contained so please clearly explain what the issue is that you are facing and then ask a question about it

@NickW Absolutlety. I've reworded my question to try and better explain my issue and actually put a question in there :) Thanks for the feedback on how to better pose a question.

Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. A recursive CTE is fully capable of returning the data you want. Alternative, explicit left joins can do it as well.

@TheImpaler added some example data! I think the way naming would work as this goes on is confusing me. I tried making some recursive CTE's but found some guides conflicting with each other and I was unable to extrapolate them into my  use case. Then I decided to post this question.

How far back do you want to go? (if the mother is represented as a Person then do we include the mothers mother?). Depending upon what you need this may not be as complex as you think (see this fiddle) but the requirements are still not really clear.

@Brits I think the number is arbitrary. Realistically it would never model beyond 2 generations so maybe 5 levels to be safe.

@Sai - OK if you want to go that far back you could end up with a lot of columns (32 the number of attributes per person). I'd suggest returning each person record and consolidating in your code (so one record per person rather than tying to put every thing into one row). It would be possible to do this in one row but you would need to write the code to unmarshal and I feel that would be more confusing. An alternative would be to return the data as JSON (a bit more difficult to write the query but probably easier to unmarshal).

Yea I ended up down this route because I was noticing how querying for each relative slowed down the db a lot so I tried to try and apply more logic in the queries to deal with that. I think I'll try and find some combination. Do you know what the query would look like for 3 generations (1 child 2 parents 4 grandparents). Not sure how to handle the dynamic naming of that many rows or how to write that recursive query, and just manually writing that query out seems verbose.

Note: This is an answer that reflects the discussion in the comments.
Given the example structure/data:
create table people
(
    uuid            text,
    givenname       text,
    surname         text,
    bio_mother_uuid text,
    bio_father_uuid text
);

insert into people (uuid, givenname, surname, bio_mother_uuid, bio_father_uuid)
values ('aa', 'david', 'smith', 'ab', 'ac'),
       ('ab', 'mary', 'smith', 'ad', 'ae'),
       ('ac', 'john', 'smith', 'af', 'ag'),
       ('ad', 'gertude', 'snow', null, 'ah'),
       ('ae', 'Richard', 'snow', null, null),
       ('af', 'Katie', 'smith', null, null),
       ('ag', 'Mathew', 'smith', null, null),
       ('ah', 'Winston', 'Snow', null, null);   

You could run a recursive CTE like:
with recursive t as (
  select 
       p.uuid    as request_uuid,
       p.uuid                 as uuid,
       p.givenname            as givenname,
       p.surname              as surname,
       p.bio_mother_uuid      as bio_mother_uuid,
       p.bio_father_uuid      as bio_father_uuid,
       0 as generation
       from people p
  union all 
  select 
       child.request_uuid    as request_uuid,
       p.uuid                 as uuid,
       p.givenname            as givenname,
       p.surname              as surname,
       p.bio_mother_uuid      as bio_mother_uuid,
       p.bio_father_uuid      as bio_father_uuid,
       child.generation + 1 as generation       
       from 
       t child join 
       people p on p.uuid = child.bio_mother_uuid or p.uuid = child.bio_father_uuid
  )
  select * from t where request_uuid = 'aa'  and generation < 3  

The result being (fiddle):



request_uuid
uuid
givenname
surname
bio_mother_uuid
bio_father_uuid
generation




aa
aa
david
smith
ab
ac
0


aa
ab
mary
smith
ad
ae
1


aa
ac
john
smith
af
ag
1


aa
ad
gertude
snow

ah
2


aa
ae
Richard
snow


2


aa
af
Katie
smith


2


aa
ag
Mathew
smith


2



This then provides all of the information needed to populate your structure (some custom code will be needed to do this). Retrieving all of the data in a single query like this is likely to be quicker than running multiple queries (but this will depend on a number of factors).
While it there may be ways to return all of this data in a single row, I feel that this would be more difficult to handle than the above (you would still need custom code to unmarshal and would have the added complexity of having to handle a varying number of columns). One alternative would be to return the structure in JSON (this would complicate the SQL but simplify your Go code).

This is great! Could you point me to any resources to both returning this in a single row and returning a JSON. I think I'm going to try all the different options and see what the benchmarks tell me. Thanks a ton!

Really just the Postgres JSON functions (these can be a bit painful to work with). The speed is unlikely to differ significantly as you will still be making a single query and transferring a comparable amount of data. Ref returning a single row; that would just be a query with lots of self joins...

I think the reason why I want them all in one row is because if I need to query for a bunch of rows then I'm unmarshalling row by row literally through a for loop so I'd have to then bounce around that iterator and have some additional logic to figure out where I'm and that I'm not messing things up in building the tree. But I CAN do that so I'll work on that.

Probably simpler to just chuck the results into a map first (then it's pretty simple to build the tree by recursively looking up the ancestors).

I wanted to come back and leave a pretty massive thank you. I used what you said and dropped the results into a map, then recursively rebuilt the base row. You can check out what I've done if you care to at the GitHub repo linked in the post at /routes/person and /models/person. Also linked so if anyone else comes to this post they can check out how I pulled it together in the final application
